# copying files within a server over SSH using Terminal - do I need to stay connected from my local machine?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I'm planning to duplicate a directory on a Linux / Apache server hosted at Dreamhost. The duplicate will stay on the server. I want to do this using SSH from Terminal in Mac OS so that I don't have to download and then re-upload the files. I plan to use the cp -R command to copy the directory [like so](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/ssh_copying.htm).

Can I start the copy process from Terminal while I am connected via SSH and then go offline (like pack up my laptop and travel) and have the copying process continue to run on the server? Or must I be connected from Terminal throughout the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answers to the question [Keeping a linux process running after I logout](https://serverfault.com/questions/311593/keeping-a-linux-process-running-after-i-logout), which was posted on Server Fault. E.g., you could establish an SSH session from your OS X system as you normally would, but you could then use the [GNU screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) utility on the SSH server to ensure the file copy operation continues after you terminate the SSH session.

> Screen is often used when a network connection to the terminal is
>   unreliable, as a dropped network connection typically terminates all
>   programs the user was running. Running the applications under screen
>   means that the applications don't even know the terminal has detached,
>   and allows the user to reattach the session later and continue working
>   from where they left off.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the server is running, the command will not stop.